# Configuring a JNDI resource that isn't a datasource in Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm trying to run an existing WebSphere application in Liberty Profile but have run into a problem.  The application has a resource environment entry configured in the server which I need to translate into a Liberty Profile resource.  How can I configure a JNDI resource in the server.xml, that isn't a datasource (dataSource) or a constant (jndiEntry)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this using the  element in the server.xml. This is documented in the [infocenter](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-libcore-mp&topic=twlp_dep_jndi). Essentially you enable the jndi feature in the server.xml using this:

```
<featureManager>
   <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Then you can configure the JNDI entries. You can only do simple types using this, so no complex objects. To configure your entry you then do this:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="myProp/philosopher" value="plato" />
```

The Liberty profile does type inference, so if you expressed this:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="myProp/philosopher" value="1234" />
```

you get an Number from JNDI. If you express this:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="myProp/philosopher" value="1234.3D" />
```

You get a Double.

If you want a number as a string literal you would express it using quotes:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="myProp/philosopher" value='"1234.3D"' />
```

To get this from your application you can do a global lookup such as:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Object jndiConstant = ctx.lookup("myProp/philosopher");
String philosopher = (String) jndiConstant;
```

You can also map this to a resource environment entry in the ibm-web-bnd.xml file:

```
<env-entry name="philosopher" binding-name="myProp/philosopher" />
```

and then use this code to look it up:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Object jndiConstant = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/philosopher");
String philosopher = (String) jndiConstant;
```

Comment: This is good information, but OP said "[not] a datasource (dataSource) or a constant (jndiEntry)".

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible with Liberty Profile. This question was answered in the IBM WasDev forum here https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/6221/resource-environment-entries-in-liberty-profile/?community=wasdev
A RFE process (31525) has been created for it to support it in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

In 8.5.5.x there are several new [entries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/search/jndi%20entry?scope=SSD28V_8.5.5):

For example: To configure an URL you can use the [jndiURLEntry](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_config_jndiURLEntry.html)