# Error - Unknown packaging eclipse plugin

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am following the ICCAD_L02_Getting_Started_Connections_Cloud.pdf document available on IBM Greenhouse. I have completed all steps succcessfuly till Step 84. 
Once I execute step 85 and complete it I get an error.

[image: Error - Step 85]

Request help in resolving the same

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the tycho plugin, what version of Eclipse do you have?  you might need to install the m2e  - look at answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767238/1873438 that should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks Paul did the changes, it worked, facing another error, was trying to log separtely, but uanble to post it due to some strange reason. Just asking here. When I run the "https://localhost:9443/mysocial.webapp/" application, I get the following error. "Error reading context properties from url/ibmsbt-sbtproperties CWNEN1001E: The object referenced by the java:comp/env/url/ibmsbt-sbtproperties JNDI name could not be instantiated" Any steps that I missed

Comment: sounds like you don't have the sbt.properties file specified on your appserver context.xml or in the websphere appserver - http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=SDK+docs#action=openDocument&res_title=Defining_a_Tomcat_server_SDK1.0&content=sdkcontent

Comment: I was able to configure it for Tomcat as mentioned. Current environment, I am using Liberty Profile. How to configure the url resource, for Liberty Profile.

Comment: add JNDI support for your profile.

Comment: How do I add the reference to the sbt.properties in server.xml as JNDI resource. jndiEntry is for simple variable. I was also referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083341/configuring-a-jndi-resource-that-isnt-a-datasource-in-liberty-profile. Any reference points that I can use.. Additionaly is it possible to remove the JNDI reference and run the app

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083341/configuring-a-jndi-resource-that-isnt-a-datasource-in-liberty-profile

Comment: Paul for now, I have bypassed the JNDI entry, and it now it seems to be working, but alas strangely. When I am running the code from my company's network, I get an unknown host exception, but working from my home network, it works properly. Not sure what is blocking, can you help me debug the issue

Comment: This is the error I get - 404 on the below url when i check in firebug. https://localhost:9443/mysocial.webapp/service/proxy/smartcloudOA2/manage/oauth/getUserIdentity?dojo.preventCache=1434472277377  - Strangely as I mentioned above works fine on my home network

Comment: do you restart the server when you change locations?